# Why does this query return more than ten rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

why does the code below return more than 10 rows? I've also tried including a `top 10` in the `sub-query`, but that didn't work either.

```
select top 10
total_worker_time/execution_count as avg_cpu_cost, query_plan,
execution_count,
(select substring(text, statement_start_offset/2 + 1,
    (case when statement_end_offset = -1
    then len(convert(varchar(max), text))* 2
    else statement_end_offset
    end - statement_start_offset)/2)
from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)) as query_text
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)
order by [avg_cpu_cost] desc
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the ONLY code you are running? It isn't possible that the code posted returns more than 10 rows.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky you should look at the query posted. You have everything you need right there in your local instance and posting sample data is actually not possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As stated by others in the comments, your query should work as expected. I tried it out by myself and I get exactly 10 rows.

Thanks to the commentors for advising me to try out things in the requested SQL engine instead of guessing what could go wrong based on experience with other engines.

<strike>Cross apply might be applied after the selection. There is no evidence for that, but I can't see anything else what can go wrong.</strike>

Comment: Not so sure about that - testing the OP code on my own db, I only get 10 rows.

Comment: What does "Cross apply is applied after the selection." mean? I am not getting what you are trying to say there.

Comment: @Nathan indeed, I tried to reproduce that. No success. But there is no other explaination, is it? But as I'm not sure anymore, I changed the wording from "is" to "might be"

Comment: No cross apply is NOT applied prior to determining which rows will be returned. That is like thinking a join is applied after the top 10. Your code won't even execute because you have an order by in  a subquery without top.

Comment: @SeanLange ty, seems that I was a bit overexcited answering the question based on experiences with other SQL engines. SQL Server seems to handle this in a more expectable way.